# A certain site is able to find the current URL of a user in somekind of an IFrame. How?

Tags: iframe, web

I found a website which is relevant to the topic that I am researching - getting an IFrame's current URL address from another domain.

Here it is:
http://hidemyipaddress.org/
(to use it simply go to the bottom, enter a website address and click "go").

You can surf any website through their website - and the amazing thing is that they can keep track of your current location, and even show it to you. (Here is a picture to illustrate: http://img199.imageshack.us/img199/6343/image2eb.jpg)

The reason I am asking is because I am trying to do the same thing.

How is this possible, isn't that XSS or something?
Thanks for taking your time on this.

Comment: They're probably routing all your requests through their server, which would make the iframe have the same origin and not be subject to security restrictions.

Comment: Does it take a lot of work to script something similar? and is that a legal website? (I think it is).